# CURAND - generating more than one quasirandom number per thread

Tags: random, cuda

I wish to generate a very large set of quasirandom numbers. (By 'very large', I mean much larger than the maximum number of concurrent threads any current CUDA device can support, 
requiring each thread to loop, or for the kernel to be launched with a large grid size. And I want quasirandom for their low-discrepancy properties.) For pseudorandoms, where each call to `curand_init` can take a different sequence parameter, [this seems simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14352953/927046).

For generating N quasirandom numbers, where N is greater than `gridDim.x * blockDim.x`, is there a solution more efficient than either

1. Running `curand_init` N times for N states, giving each call a *unique* offset in [0, N);
2. Running `curand_init` only `gridDim.x * blockDim.x` times for that number of states, but giving each call an offset of e.g. `10*threadID`, if I expect each thread to have to generate 10 numbers?

(Ignoring any overhead due to large offsets, i.e. ignoring `skip_ahead()`.)

---

I had a look at the code in the CUDA 6.0 samples, and MC_EstimatePiInlineQ *appeared* to do what I was looking for in two dimensions. However, when the number of points to generate exceeds `gridDim.x * blockDim.x`, I believe this code actually produces the same points *multiple times*. This is an issue since `gridDim.x` is not necessarily large enough to fit the problem size in this example; it is tuned to target roughly 10 blocks per multiprocessor on the device.

The relevant code is below (slightly altered for brevity):

```
// RNG init kernel
template <typename rngState_t, typename rngDirectionVectors_t>
__global__ void initRNG(rngState_t *const rngStates,
                        rngDirectionVectors_t *const rngDirections)
{
    // Determine thread ID
    unsigned int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int step = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;

    // Initialise the RNG
    curand_init(rngDirections[0], tid, &rngStates[tid]);
    curand_init(rngDirections[1], tid, &rngStates[tid + step]);
}
```

and,

```
// Estimator kernel
template <typename Real, typename rngState_t>
__global__ void computeValue(unsigned int *const results,
                             rngState_t *const rngStates,
                             const unsigned int numSims)
{
    // Determine thread ID
    unsigned int bid = blockIdx.x;
    unsigned int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int step = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;

    // Initialise the RNG
    rngState_t localState1 = rngStates[tid];
    rngState_t localState2 = rngStates[tid + step];

    // Count the number of points which lie inside the unit quarter-circle
    unsigned int pointsInside = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = tid ; i < numSims ; i += step)
    {
        Real x = curand_uniform(&localState1);
        Real y = curand_uniform(&localState2);

        // Do something.
    }

    // Do some more.
}
```

Suppose `gridDim.x * blockDim.x < N`, then at least thread `tid = 0` will loop twice in the `for`. In its second run, it will generate the second random number relative to its initializing offset of 0; this is equivalent to the first random number relative to an initializing offset of 1, which is exactly what `tid = 1` did the *first* time. So the point already has already been generated! This is true for all threads except the one with the highest `tid` (i.e. some multiple of `gridDim.x * blockDim.x`), if it is even looping more than once. At best this is useless work, and for my use-case it will be harmful.

I have created a [stripped-down version](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a202065b19f017f6f9be) of the mentioned example, based on some hypothetical device, where we have only 4 threads per block, and only 2 blocks, but wish to generate 16 points. Note that lines 9-15 of the output are identical to lines 2-8. Only line 16 is a new point.

Comment: presumably you mean `curand_init` and not `cuda_init` in the introduction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a case of reading [the docs](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/device-api-overview.html), but in practice I've found it can indeed be substantially faster to limit the number of states you generate.

This corresponds to option 2 in the question: each thread's `offset` to `curand_init` should be `n * tid` where `n` is at least as great as the number of random numbers you wish each thread to generate. If that isn't know at state-generation, you can instead use [`skip_ahead(n * tid, &state)`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/device-api-overview.html#skip-ahead) before calling `curand`, `curand_uniform` etc.